# TypeScript. Ambient declaration was not found when importing "module/subdirectory" npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, module, node-modules

I am developing a library called `'vee-type-safe'` for runtime type checking. Everything worked beautifully untill I added a subdirectory `/express` and a file `/express/index.ts` where I export some `ExpressJS` middleware type checking factories. 
So I have the following structure:

```
vee-type-safe
|- build
|- package.json
|- declarations
|  |- is-iso-date.d.ts
|
|- tsconfig.json
|- index.ts       // lightweight core library
|- express
   |-index.ts     // express middleware factories
```

In `express/index.ts` file I import my library core `'../index.ts'` module.
In my core module I have the following import:

```
import isISODate = require('is-iso-date');
```

`'is-iso-date'` package has no typings, so I created `declarations` directory with `is-iso-date.d.ts` which is as simple as this:

```
declare module 'is-iso-date' {
    function isISODate(suspect: string): boolean;
    export = isISODate;
}
```

I added `"typeRoots": [ ..., "declarations"]` to `tsconfig.json`

I added `"types": "build/index.d.ts"` to `package.json`

When I run `tsc` in my package everything compiles with no errors.
But when I install my `'vee-type-safe'` library as a dependency to some project via npm and try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'is-iso-date'. 
'/home/tegeran/projects/is-iso-date-issue/node_modules/is-iso-date/index.js'
implicitly has an 'any'type.
Try `npm install @types/is-iso-date` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
file containing `declare module 'is-iso-date';`

1 import isISODate = require('is-iso-date');
```

This happens only when I import `'vee-type-safe/express'` submodule. When I import my core `'vee-type-safe'` module, no errors are generated. What am I missing here?
I created [a github repo with a bare minimum project to demonstrate this error](https://github.com/Veetaha/ambient-declaration-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `tsc` on the outer project, the `tsconfig.json` file of `vee-type-safe` is not in effect, so nothing forces `tsc` to load `vee-type-safe/declarations/is-iso-date.d.ts`.  For an import of `vee-type-safe`, this is OK because the `types` field of `vee-type-safe/package.json` redirects to `vee-type-safe/build/index.d.ts`, which does not refer to `is-iso-date` since `vee-type-safe/index.ts` uses `is-iso-date` only in the implementation and does not expose any types from it.  However, an import of `vee-type-safe/express` bypasses `vee-type-safe/package.json` and loads `vee-type-safe/express/index.ts` directly, and that file imports `vee-type-safe/index.ts`, which imports `is-iso-date`, and you get the error.  More importantly, the import of `vee-type-safe/express` won't work at runtime because it doesn't resolve to a `.js` file.

You have a few options to fix this, none of them great:

1. *(Deleted)*
2. Have the outer project import `vee-type-safe/build/express`, which will resolve to `vee-type-safe/build/express/index.d.ts`.
3. Remove the `outDir` option from `vee-type-safe` so that the `.d.ts` files are generated alongside the `.ts` files.
4. Redirect `vee-type-safe/express` (and each other submodule path you want other projects to be able to import) individually to the proper files under `build` by manually creating either a pair of `.js` and `.d.ts` files that import the real paths or a `package.json` file with `main` and `types` fields that refer to the real paths.  (Update: It looks like `main` is enough because TypeScript will try changing the extension of the `main` path.)

See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8305) for additional discussion.

Comment: Thank you, I've already resolved this issue using the 4-th option having an individual `package.json` for my `express` submodule, though I only specified `"main": "../build/express/index.js` property without `"types"` and everything works fine, *hmm...* I don't even know why(. However, thank you for your splendid explanation )